# One table filter is working fine for me but ,here i need to filter two tables filter in django which is not working

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class Department(models.Model):
    department_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    department_n_key = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,unique=True)
    hospital_short_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class EmployeesMaster(models.Model):
    employee_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    employee_n_key = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)

class PatientMaster(models.Model):
    patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    patient_n_key = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True,unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

views.py

i need to apply this in django:

SELECT * FROM `appointment_master` WHERE `patient_type`='something' and`appointment_master`.`department_n_key` IN (SELECT `department`.`department_n_key` FROM `department` WHERE `department`.`department_name`='something')

help somebody to apply  this in django

Answer (score 0):

It's not optimal but you can do it in two Queries

```
departments_list= Department.objects.filter(departmen_name='foo').values_list('department_n_key', flat=True)

apointment_master = YourModel.objects.filter(patient_type='bar', department_n_key__in=departments_list)
```